# converting docx to pdf

Tags: java, pdf, docx4j

I am converting docx to pdf which works fine. But the problem is it misses the formatting the document. How to ensure the formatting such as `[bold, tablets etc]]` are not lost while converting.

I am using `docx4j` for `conversion`.

```
Below is the exception I am getting

NOT IMPLEMENTED: support for w:ptab -
NOT IMPLEMENTED: support for w:ptab -3
NOT IMPLEMENTED: support for w:altChunk -
NOT IMPLEMENTED: support for w:altChunk -
NOT IMPLEMENTED: support for w:altChunk -
NOT IMPLEMENTED: support for w:altChunk -
NOT IMPLEMENTED: support for w:altChunk -
NOT IMPLEMENTED: support for w:altChunk -
```

Comment: Hehe. I had the same issue. Someone answered: "Correctly parsing a .docx and then generating a PDF from it is very hard. Writing something that remotely works costs man-years (plural)". In the end I used Libreoffice in unix with "libreoffice --headless --convert-to pdf filename.docx" - the result is quite good but convertings always shreds the layout :(

Comment: What version of docx4j are you using?  Bold should generally appear ..  and with the current docx4j nightly, you won't need that setHeaderExtent trick.

Comment: @JasonPlutext: I am using 3.0.1 version. I am getting the NOT IMPLEMENTD: support for w:altChunk error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**ptab**: as it says, there is currently no support for the [ptab](http://webapp.docx4java.org/OnlineDemo/ecma376/WordML/ptab.html) element.  Its not commonly used.  You can either remove it from your docx, or we could look at adding support for it to docx4j.

**altChunk**: these need to be preprocessed into "real" docx content for docx4j's PDF output.  If the altChunk is of type XHTML, docx4j can do that. If it is a docx altChunk, the Enterprise Edition is required. There are other types of altChunks, which you should avoid if you want to convert to PDF...